# VC++ Windows Application ListView delete all selected items

Tags: .net, winforms, listview, visual-c++

I am trying to delete multiple selected items from the *listView1* but it appears that after deleting one item, the list is not getting updated and hence the *program is malfunctioning i.e. deleting some wrong items* and skipping some right ones.

After one item is deleted, the *GUI box is updated* i.e. the item gets disappeared from the box. But the next item after the first one is not what it should be.

**Example:** I select items with indices 0, 1, 3, 4

**Result:** 0 is deleted, then 3 is deleted, then 5 is deleted even though I did not select 5.

**Note:** The items are being selected correctly (*I tested*). The problem lies in the code below.

**Here is my code:**

```
private: System::Void delSelected_LinkClicked(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs^  e)
{
    int count = listView1->SelectedItems->Count;
    ListView::SelectedIndexCollection^ indexes = this->listView1->SelectedIndices;
    System::Collections::IEnumerator^ myEnum1 = indexes->GetEnumerator();
    MessageBox::Show(count.ToString(), "MessageBox Test", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Information);

    while (myEnum1->MoveNext()) {
        int index = safe_cast<int>(myEnum1->Current);
        //MessageBox::Show(index.ToString()+". "+listView1->Items[index]->Text, "MessageBox Test", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Information);
        listView1->Items->Remove(listView1->Items[index]);
    }
}
```

I would like to know a way to update the list after one item is deleted or any other workaround.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listview items are deleted by their index (that is, their position in the list, from 0 through to n-1).

The problem is that when a listview item is deleted, all the **subsequent** items are moved up by one position. For example, if you delete item index 1, the item that was previously index 2 becomes the new index 1, and so on.

The solution is either to:

- Keep track of the number of items you have deleted, and subtract that total from the index when you delete each subsequent item, or
- Delete the items in reverse order

No matter which solution you choose, you need to make sure the list of indices to be deleted is sorted before you start.

Comment: Being a beginner, I did not know that the list is moved up. I opted for the delete-in-reverse-order solution and it is working perfectly.

Thanks for the precise and accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a a straight-forward way to compliment Jonathan's answer:

```
while (listView1->SelectedItems->Count > 0)
{
    listView1->Items->Remove(listView1->SelectedItems [0]);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this code will even work correctly. Don't you need to decrement the Count? And also, what if the selected items are not in the beginning of the list and also not in consecutive order?

Check my answer to see how I did it.

Comment: @ITFreak: Firstly, the `Remove` method of the `ItemCollection` of the `ListView` will automatically decrement its `Count` property. Secondly, the `SelectedItems` property is also updated every time you add or remove rows from the listview. Give it a try.

Comment: Fixed a typo to use `SelectedItems` in all three places.

Comment: There is one more mistake i.e. Remove is not a member of SelectedItems. It is the member of Items. 

Your code works perfectly with that correction, thanks.

Comment: @ITFreak: Thanks. Corrected it. Not wise to answer SO questions without an IDE at hand :).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it with the help of Jonathan and Raheel's answers:

```
while (listView1->SelectedItems->Count > 0)
    listView1->Items->Remove(listView1->SelectedItems[0])
```